# Convert UTF-8 to string literals in Python

Tags: python, string, utf-8, literals

I have a string in UTF-8 format but not so sure how to convert this string to it's corresponding character literal. For example I have the string:

My string is: `'Entre\xc3\xa9'`

Example one:

This code:

```
u'Entre\xc3\xa9'.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
```

returns the result: `u'Entre\xe9'`

If I then continue by printing this:

```
print u'Entre\xe9'
```

I get the result: `Entreé`

This is great and close to what I need. The problem is, I can't make 'Entre\xc3\xa9' a variable and pass it through the steps as this now breaks. Any tips for getting this working?

Example:

```
a = 'Entre\xc3\xa9'
b = 'u'+ a.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
c= 'u'+ b
```

I would like result of "c" to be:

```
Entreé
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `u''` syntax *only works for string literals*, e.g. defining values in source code. Using the syntax results in a `unicode` object being created, but that's not the only way to create such an object.

You cannot make a `unicode` value from a byte string by adding `u` in front of it. But if you called `str.decode()` with the right encoding, you get a `unicode` value. Vice-versa, you can *encode* `unicode` objects to byte strings with `unicode.encode()`.

Note that when displaying a `unicode` object, Python *represents* it by using the Unicode string literal syntax again (so `u'...'`), to ease debugging. You can paste the representation back in to a Python interpreter and get an object with the same value.

Your `a` value is defined using a byte string literal, so you only need to decode:

```
a = 'Entre\xc3\xa9'
b = a.decode('utf8')
```

Your first example created a [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake), a Unicode string containing Latin-1 codepoints that actually represent UTF-8 bytes. This is why you had to encode to Latin-1 first (to undo the Mojibake), then decode from UTF-8.

You may want to read up on Python and Unicode in the [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html). Other articles of interest are:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder

Comment: Many Thanks!

So now if I enter: b 
into the python interpreter I get: u'Entre\xe9'
If I enter: print b 
I get: Entreé

Is it possible to have a string variable that will automatically return Entreé without using the print statement?

Comment: @user3804963: I think you are confusing the representation (`u'Entre\xe9'`) with the value. `print` shows you the value (as encoded for your terminal), while your python console shows you the representation (for debugging). No value change has taken place. Python is showing you a value that can be copied and pasted into your source code without having to declare a source code encoding beyond the default ASCII, so an escape sequence (`\xe9`) is shown for the U+00E9 Unicode codepoint. **This is normal**.