# how can I get a valid object id of mongodb from a string?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, objectid

I want to make my mongodb OjectId to a field:

```
class ZhinengStats(Document):
    zhineng_id = ObjectIdField(db_field="_id", primary_key=True, required=True, help_text="job id")
```

but a valid ObjectId must be a 12-byte input of type 'str' or a 24-character hex string, so if I do this:

```
ZhinengStats.objects(zhineng_id="programmer").first()
```

I will get an error. I thought a hash is a good way:

```
hash("programmer") # 7354308922443094682
```

but as you can see, hash seems not ok.

So how can I get a valid object id?

---

UPDATE:

the main problem is because this is field is a chinese, so something like this:`ObjectId('兼职'.decode("utf-8"))` can not work, so how can I make this support utf-8?

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3 ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux python 2

Comment: **Check this link will help you** https://stackoverflow.com/a/66117385/9416032

Answer (score 3):

Is there any reason why you must generate the ObjectId from a string? If you simply wants an unique id for your mongodb document, you can generate one automatically like so

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
_id = ObjectId()
```

the ObjectId generated will be based on the machine's hardware signature, and the current time

Answer (score 1):

[Python mongodb documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/objectid.html) has examples ready for you:

> class bson.objectid.ObjectId(oid=None)
>
> Initialize a new ObjectId.

```
ObjectId(b'foo-bar-quux')
ObjectId('666f6f2d6261722d71757578')
```

Comment: I have a problem with this, chinese is not ok, such as ObjectId(u"兼职") returns `bson.errors.InvalidId: u'\u517c\u804c' is not a valid ObjectId, it must be a 12-byte input of type 'str' or a 24-character hex string`

Comment: @roger may be this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571790/convert-utf-8-to-string-literals-in-python

Comment: you mean `ObjectId("兼职".decode("utf-8"))`? this can not work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the string is in variable **rndId**, do the following:

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

rndId="1234"
collection.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(rndId)
```

*** Pre-install the bson package dependency :

```
> pip install bson
```