# How to convert a unicode string to a literal string in Python?

Tags: python, string, unicode, encode, string-literals

Here are a few examples (unicode) string:

```
a = u'\u03c3\u03c4\u03b7\u03bd \u03a0\u03bb\u03b1\u03c4\u03b5\u03af\u03b1 \u03c4\u03bf\u03c5'
b = u'\u010deprav so mu doma\u010di in strici duhovniki odtegovali denarno pomo\u010d . Kljub temu mu je uspelo'
c = u'sovi\xe9ticas excepto Georgia , inclusive las 3 rep\xfablicas que hab\xedan'
```

My end goal is to split on the backslashes (and spaces), so that it looks like this:

```
split_a = [u03c3, u03c4, u03b7, u03bd, ,u03a0, u03bb, u03b1, u03c4, u03b5, u03af, u03b1, ,u03c4, u03bf, u03c5]
split_b = ['', 'u010deprav', 'so', 'mu', 'doma', 'u010di', 'in', 'strici',  'duhovniki' odtegovali denarno pomo', 'u010d', '.', 'Kljub', 'temu', 'mu', 'je', 'uspelo']
split_c = ['sovi', 'xe9ticas', 'excepto', 'Georgia', ',', 'inclusive', 'las', '3',  'rep', 'xfablicas', 'que', 'hab', 'xedan']
```

(The empty places where there is both a space and a backslash are totally fine).

When I try to split using this:

`a.split("\\")`, it doesn't change the string at all.

I saw this example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047976/split-a-string-by-backslash-in-python), which makes me think that I need to make my strings literal strings (using `r`). However, I don't know how to convert my large list of strings into all literal strings.

When I searched on that, I got [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571790/convert-utf-8-to-string-literals-in-python). However, my compiler throws an error when I run `a.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')`. The error it throws is `'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(256)`

So, my question is: How can I take a list of unicode strings, programmatically iterate through them and make them string literals, and then split on a backslash?

Comment: Python is an interpreted language, so the Python interpreter throws the error.

Comment: I think you're a bit above my level here, but thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `unicode_escape` code to translate a unicode string to its escaped representation.

```
split_a = a.encode('unicode_escape').split('\\')
```

outputs:

```
['',
 'u03c3',
 'u03c4',
 'u03b7',
 'u03bd ',
 'u03a0',
 'u03bb',
 'u03b1',
 'u03c4',
 'u03b5',
 'u03af',
 'u03b1 ',
 'u03c4',
 'u03bf',
 'u03c5']
```

Comment: This worked for me if I then iterated through the `split_a` list and further `split` on " " (space).

Answer (score 3):

You have a Unicode string, which already has one Unicode codepoint per string element. The `'\\'` is just the representation of the string that is printed to the console, it's not the actual contents.

To make a list of numbers out of it is actually quite easy:

```
split_a = [ord(c) for c in a]
```

If you need to make a bunch of strings consisting of the letter `u` followed by the hex value, that's only slightly more complicated:

```
split_a = ', '.join('u' + ('%04x' % ord(c)) for c in a)
```

Comment: The second one solved my problem for my example above. I've edited my question to include some more sample unicode strings, let me know if you have a solution for those other types of strings.

Comment: Was just about to push submit on a similar solution, so I'll just add a follow up comment - you'd have to do a bit more work to only display the values for characters that are unknown encodings. Specifically, in the OP's example, rendering the space character as " ", vs. "u0020".

Comment: @python_in_trouble wow, that's a completely different problem now, much more complex.